# Enumerating sums of integers

Tags: combinatorics

So I found a question which seems to be really easy to answer but after thinking a lot about it, well, I've have to say, I came up with nothing.

So here's the question:

> Assume the sum of $a+b+c+d+e+f$ that each of the numbers can be $0,3,4,5$, how many different summations can exist?

The only point I came up with is that the integer $0$ doesn't change the summation therefore different permutations of a $0$ count as one as I said the reason above.

And sorry if the Tags are irrelevant and my Math language is crappy I'm a newbie!

Please feel free to edit my tags I really do not know which one to add.

Any help would be highly appreciated in advance.

Comment: How so?Can you explain your answer?

Comment: Do you want to know how many different **sums** there are? Or how many *ordered* sextuples there are? Or how many *unordered* sectuples there are?

Comment: @AndréNicolas What i want to know is that how many different answers can this sum have.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly.  The smallest possible sum is $0$ (if all the numbers are $0$) and the largest possible sum is $30$ (if all the numbers are $5$).  The only numbers in between that *cannot* be written as a sum of at most six $3$'s, $4$'s and $5$'s are $1$ and $2$.  So I get a total of $29$ different summations.

Comment: @math137 This absolutely wrong! 5+5+5+5+5+5=30 right?

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks barry your answer is correct but can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @FuriousMathematician, the numbers $6$ to $10$ can be written as the sum of *two* numbers:  $6=3+3$, $7=3+4$, $8=3+5$, $9=4+5$, and $10=5+5$.  Therefore the numbers $11$ to $15$ can be written as the sum of *three* numbers, by adding another $5$ to each of what we just wrote.  After that, $16$ to $20$ can be written as the sum of four numbers, and so forth.

Comment: @barryCipra Now that's an understandable version!Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the set of all possible sums by $S$. Clearly $S\subset\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,30\}$.

Then take care of each element in $\{0,1,\cdots,30\}$.

$30=5+5+5+5+5+5$

$29=5+5+5+5+5+4$

$28=5+5+5+5+5+3$

$27=5+5+5+5+4+3$

$26=5+5+5+5+3+3$

Replacing one 5 by 0, we can obtain $25,24,23,22,21$. Repeat this process for 4 times until we get

$10=0+0+0+0+5+5$

$9=0+0+0+0+5+4$

$8=0+0+0+0+5+3$

$7=0+0+0+0+4+3$

$6=0+0+0+0+3+3$.

Then we see $S=\{0,3,4,5\}\cup\{6,7,\cdots,30\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!I absolutely get it by do you know an easier way for it as I have to explain it to a 13-year-old guy? :D

Comment: The argument would be to show that because $3,4,5$ are consecutive, you can express any number between $3k$ and $5k$ as the sum of $k$ of these digits.  The fact that you also have $0$ available means that you can vary $k$.  Using zero non-zero digits, you can only express the numbers between $0\cdot 3$ and $0\cdot 5$ (i.e. $0$). Using one non-zero digit, you can express the numbers between $3$ and $5$.  Using two non-zero digits, you can express numbers between $2\cdot 3$ and $2\cdot 5$.  From this point, successive ranges of expressible start to overlap (since $5k\geq 3(k+1)$ for $k\geq 2$).

Answer (score 0):

The smallest possible sum is $0+0+0+0+0+0=0$.  The largest is $5+5+5+5+5+5=30$.  It is also obvious that you can't have a sum of $1$ or $2$.  So, we have an upper bound of $29$ possible sums.

Can you find a quick proof that all the numbers from $3$ to $29$ are possible sums?

Answer (score 0):

The number of solutions is $29$.

The smallest sum that you can get is then $0+0+0+0+0+0=0$ and the highest is $5+\dots+5=30$. You can of course not get $1$ or $2$, so you have at most $29$ sums. It remains to find that you get exactly $29$ sums.

By adding only fives you can get $$\{5n\mid n=0,\dots 6\}.$$

By adding one $3$ or one $4$ and all others fives you can get $$\{5n+3\mid n=0,\dots 5\},$$ $$\{5n+4\mid n=0,\dots 5\}.$$
By choosing $3+3$ or $3+4$ you get
$$\{5n+6\mid n=0,\dots 4\},$$ 
$$\{5n+7\mid n=0,\dots 4\}.$$
This shows that you get $29$ distinct numbers.